# Server.MapPath vs Request.MapPath

Tags: server.mappath

Can someone please explain the difference between Server.MapPath and Request.MapPath and usage scenarios for the two ?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has provided at least three different public MapPath methods since version 2.0:

- [HttpRequest.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.mappath.aspx)
- [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)
- [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx)

Internally, `HttpServerUtility.MapPath` calls `HttpRequest.MapPath`.

`HostingEnvironment.MapPath` is a static method, throws an `ArgumentNullException` if the argument is null or empty, and throws an `ArgumentException` if the argument is a relative path.

`HttpRequest.MapPath` is not a static method and does not throw the exceptions mentioned above.